# Python pyautogui Attribute error display mouse position

Tags: python

Okay, so i installed pyautogui and when i open up a python shell and write in this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

i get this error in a red text that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'displayMousePosition'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation for `pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples), you seem to be looking for

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.position() # Get the XY position of the mouse.
```

Not sure where you got `displayMousePosition()` from.

Comment: Oh, I was looking at a tutorial which he did displayMousePosition() that printed the x and y position as well as the RGB values, and when i type in pyautogui.position() i still get this attribute error. (edit) I get Attribute errors on all pyautogui commands for some reason

Comment: If you happen to have a file called `pyautogui.py` or similar in your directory, that may be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui
x = pyautogui.position().x # Get X position
y = pyautogui.position().y # Get Y position

print("Position:", x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the IDLE shell as administrator. I had the same problem and launching with administrator privileges worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `Pillow` package in order to use `pyautogui.displayMousePosition()`.

You can install it using the command

`python -m pip install Pillow`

Then run your code and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pyautogui

try:

    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

except AttributeError:

    from sys import *

    from subprocess import *

    call([executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "Pillow"])
```

Try this and pls tell if it works

Comment: Please explain the issue.

Comment: It's because you haven't installed the "Pillow" module :)